# Positioning a % sized sprite sheet background in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a card matching memory game. I have 10 different images that represent the card faces which I have arranged on a spite sheet that's 620px wide and 62px high.

Each card is represented on the page by a DIV element.

```
<div class="card guitar"></div>
<div class="card drums"></div>
<div class="card piano"></div>
<div class="card trumpet"></div>
....
```

I have set the background of the card elements with the following CSS...

```
.card {
    background-image: url(/img/cards.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1000% 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    width: 8rem;
}
```

And then for each individual card I position the background...

```
.card.guitar { background-position: 0 0; }
.card.drums { background-position: 10% 0; }
.card.piano { background-position: 20% 0; }
.card.trumpet { background-position: 30% 0; }
....
```

It was my assumption that setting the background image to 1000% would make it appear 10 times larger than the div it's assigned to. Then for .drums setting 10% background position would move the background along by one width of the div.

The problem is that the backgrounds don't appear to sit in the correct place!

---

**EDIT.**

JSFiddle as requested http://jsfiddle.net/LPfcp/

Comment: Can you give us jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Side note : I hope your players won't have acces to webmaster tools otherwise it's going to be pretty easy for them to identify the cards with the class...

Comment: did you mean `sprite` instead of `spite`?

Comment: `background-position` is relative to the element's width, not relative to `background-size`, so in this case, you have to use `100%` (not `10%`).

Comment: @web-tiki that's ok, it's just a single player thing anyway so people would only be cheating themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-position`, when used with a percentage, aligns that percentage of the element with that percentage of the image. Example:

```
[||||              ] Image at 0%
[       ||||       ] Image at 50%
[              ||||] Image at 100%
```

Does that make sense?

With this in mind, you will need 11%, 22%, 33%, 44%, 56%, 67%, 78%, 89% and 100%. Note that it won't be completely accurate because 100% doesn't divide nicely by nine.

Consider arranging your items into a better-dividing order, like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

Then you can have positions of `0% 0%`, `25% 0%`, `50% 0%`, `75% 0%` and `100% 0%` for the top row, and `0% 100%`, `25% 100%`, `50% 100%`, `75% 100%` and `100% 100%` for the bottom row.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the background is not eddited properly to be resized to 1000%
So you have to do this:

```
.card.guitar { background-position: 0 0; }
.card.drums { background-position: 10% 0; }
.card.piano { background-position: 22.2% 0; }
.card.trumpet { background-position: 33.3% 0; }
```